# Laravel validation exists in database (different schema) in a transaction

Tags: php, validation, laravel, connection, schema

I have a relationship, let's say user and photos for the sake of simplicity, and I only want to save the user if all photos are saved. So in the Photo model I have a validation rule like:

```
user_id => exists:schema.user,id
```

(I have a different connection for every schema, named after them)

My controller method looks something like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$user = User::create(request()->except('photos'));
$photos = $user->photos()->createMany(request()->input('photos'));
DB::commit();
```

But the model validation fails with "user_id does not exists". I think it's because Laravel uses the 'schema' connection, and it doesn't see the changes from the transaction, which is started on the default (and different) connection.

How can I write a validation rule that fits this case?

Comment: I dont' think that has somethink with a transaction. It smells like your relation lacks user_id. Are you sure that photos table has `user_id` field? If yes then could you `dd($user->getKey())` just after `User::create(...)`?

Comment: I dumped the User::find($photo->user_id) with the failing photo, and it found the User

Comment: So are you sure that you have user_id in photos table?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure, I'm using it elsewhere too

Comment: Plus, if I comment out the transaction, it works fine

Comment: When the validation is triggered out?

Comment: In Model::saving() it returns false to prevent saving invalid models

Comment: Try to validate before transaction. Thats the correct way of doing it. It's got to have `Service Layer` between controller and model that is using the model's repository. Validating on event trigger is not so good - in case of such a situation. Read about Service Bus or alternatively about CQRS.

Comment: I can't create a Photo for a non-existing User, so I have to create the User first, then the Photos. Also, it's in the model so it validates automatically every time, even when I update or create the Photo somewhere else. Plus I have to validate before sending it to the database, otherwise the foreign key will throw the same error with an invalid id.